# Openedge progress - Can't escape single quote - Is this a bug?

Tags: database, openedge, progress-db

I am trying to run a simple query over jdbc ALTER TABLE Customer ALTER \"Cust-Name\" set PRO_DESCRIPTION 'Customer Name'
This works perfectly well. But, when I have to set description as "Customer's Name", i.e, include a single quote - I am unable to get it to work.

I tried

```
ALTER TABLE Customer ALTER \"Cust-Name\" set PRO_DESCRIPTION 'Customer~'s Name'
ALTER TABLE Customer ALTER \"Cust-Name\" set PRO_DESCRIPTION 'Customer~~'s Name'
ALTER TABLE Customer ALTER \"Cust-Name\" set PRO_DESCRIPTION 'Customer\\'sName'
ALTER TABLE Customer ALTER \"Cust-Name\" set PRO_DESCRIPTION "Customer's Name"
```

Nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Progress, but the SQL standard is to duplicate the single quote:

```
'Customer''s Name'
```

Comment: Your my friend are a fine horse!! :) Thank you, that helped. Was banging my head for two days over this. Thank You, Thank You, Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

While I was learning Progress I encountered a function called QUOTER that can be used in your situation.

> QUOTER function
>
> ---
>
> Converts the specified data type to CHARACTER and encloses the results
>   in quotes when necessary.
>
> The QUOTER function is intended for use in QUERY-PREPARE where a
>   character predicate must be created from a concatenated list of string
>   variables to form a WHERE clause. In order to process variables,
>   screen values, and input values so that they are suitable for a query
>   WHERE clause, it is often necessary to enclose them in quotes. For
>   example, European-format decimals and character variables must always
>   be enclosed in quotes. You can use the Quoter function to meet that
>   requirement.